# Android SearchView getting filtered array?

Tags: android, listview, searchview

I want to implement SearchView to my application .List searching fine only.My question how to get filtered array or while searching particular index value getting.Is there any possible please let me know.Thanks in advance.
My code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        SearchView searchItem = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchItem.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchItem.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        searchItem.setFocusable(true);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
        return false;
    }
```

Here arrayAdapter is my list adapter.

Comment: I did not understand your question. Can you ask it again?

Comment: I need while searching ListView reduced as per the searching words but while clicking particular index how to get particular index value?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to know the index

```
        searchItem.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //your code here
            }
        });
```

Comment: searchView didn't have setOnItemClickListener property.